# Rounding R simple features linestring geometry coordinates

Tags: r, performance, geospatial, r-sf

I need to round the coordinates of a simple features object (containing approx. 1,000,000 linestring features) to the nearest 5 decimal places. The code below does this correctly, but runtime is very slow because the last line of the for loop (indata$geometry[i] <- st_linestring(coords) takes several seconds for each iteration.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to code this?

```
indata <- st_read(dsn=dir, layer=layer)
indata <- st_cast(indata,"LINESTRING")

for (i in 1:nrow(indata)) {
  coords <- st_coordinates(indata$geometry[i])
  coords <- round(coords, 5)
  indata$geometry[i] <- st_linestring(coords) #This is the slow part
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can improve much upon what you have without writing out a shapefile. The limitation seems to be dealing with linestring. However, you can use the `st_set_precision` function to set the precision and write out a file. It doesn't change the geometry precision until your write a file. You can read more about how precision works in the `st_binary` section of the sf manual on [page 48](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf) of the sf manual. Basically it is related to the number of zeros.

```
outdata <- st_set_precision(indata, precision=10^5)
st_write(outdata, "/path/to/file.shp")
indata <- st_read("/path/to/file.shp")
```

Comment: thank you, that you need to save the files and reimport them to get the precision setting to work is missing from the documentation https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_precision.html