# How can I use write_sf in R to limit the number of decimal places in the DBF?

Tags: r, gis, gdal, r-sf, rgdal

I have had issues with writing new shapefiles and limiting the number of decimal places in the DBF file. My code is rather simple :

```
write_sf(temp_points, "temp_points.shp")
```

and even though the input data didn't have so many decimal places, the output from R looks like this :
[I would like to reduce the number of decimal places to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNs2U.png)

Is there anything I can add to the write_sf function to limit the number of decimal places?

UPDATE 1:
I've now tried :

```
write_sf(st_set_precision(temp_points,0.01), "temp_points.shp")
```

and I still get the same results. The st_set_precision function works in RStudio, but as soon as I open the DBF file afterwards, it looks the same as before with all those zeroes.

Comment: ```st_set_precision```

Comment: If you mean opening it in ArcGIS, then there is no way to do it with `sf`: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267757/fix-the-data-type-properties-of-fields-when-a-shapefile-is-manipulated-in-r maybe there is a way with ```library(arcgisbinding)```

Comment: You are using st_set_precision incorrectly. It should be 10^2 instead of 0.01. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142804/rounding-r-simple-features-linestring-geometry-coordinates.